# Issues Related to Google Play Developer Console – Alpha Testing

Tags: android

1. Can I update an apk which has been uploaded for Alpha/beta Testing ?
   that is I have created alpha testing and the testers sent their feedback regarding some bugs to be fixed , I have fixed them now I want to update the apk which is in alpha testing is it possible or i have to make a new alpha testing ?
2. Is it possible to transfer an apk which is currently in alpha/beta testing to the production without the need to upload the same apk to the production ? ,  assuming that the apk has no bugs , and the testing was done by testers without reporting any bugs .

Answer (score 1):

1. You can upload a new APK to Google Play with the changes. Just ensure that you change the build version etc.
2. You can promote any alpha or beta app by simply going to developer console -> APK -> navigate to current apk in Alpha or Beta -> Find promote drop down -> click either Promote to Beta or Promote to production.